# Best method to replace a string with a string containing backslashes (\)

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to update a stored NT account (Domain\user) with a new account. The new account comes as a String object.

I call my replaceAccount method to perform this, by running this line:

```
tempAcct.setDefinition(ExtractNTAccount.matcher(tempAcct.getDefinition()).replaceFirst("nt=\""+newNTLogin+"\""));
```

If the NT Account is "HOME\jdoe", and I then output the definition field of tempAcct, I see the NT login as "HOMEjdoe" instead.

By checking the replaceFirst method javadoc, the following can be read:

> "Note that backslashes () and dollar
>   signs ($) in the replacement string
>   may cause the results to be different
>   than if it were being treated as a
>   literal replacement string; see
>   Matcher.replaceFirst(java.lang.String).
>   Use
>   Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)
>   to suppress the special meaning of
>   these characters, if desired."

So, I've found that if instead of passing the NT account as it is ("HOME\jdoe") I pass **"HOME"+Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\")+"jdoe"**, or **"HOME\\\\jdoe"**, I then get correct results after using the replaceFirst method.

Is this the best method we can use or I'm totally misunderstanding how to use the Matcher.quoteReplacement() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of `replaceFirst()` is treated as an expression where `$` and `\` have a special meaning. If you want it to be treated as a literal string instead, you quote it with `Matcher.quoteReplacement()`:

```
tempAcct.setDefinition(ExtractNTAccount.matcher(
    tempAcct.getDefinition()).replaceFirst(
         Matcher.quoteReplacement("nt=\"" + newNTLogin + "\"")));
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually just discovered this. I was using it at the incorrect level.